# Wiggly paragraph and h2 after hover on button

Tags: html, css

When I hover on my button my H2 and paragraph wiggle. How can I prevent it? As you can see I would like to add more border during hovering. Is it a cause this situation?

[image]

```css
.about-me-wrapper {
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 10em auto;
  height: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.about-me-wrapper p {
  width: 70%;
  line-height: 1.75;
}

.about-me-wrapper a {
  background: transparent;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  margin: 20px 0;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transition: all .4s;
  display: inline-block;
}

.about-me-wrapper a:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 3px solid #4EADFF;
  color: #4EADFF;
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

```html
<section class="about-me">
  <div class="about-me-wrapper">
    <h2>Aarhus Lejerboliger</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    <a href="#">View project</a>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Yes, the different border width causes this effect. You could either use an outline instead of a border (outline does not influence an element's dimensions), or make up the difference by calculating it into the margin of the element on hover.

Comment: I don't see any wiggle on Chrome/Mac

Comment: I am unable to see the so called 'wiggle'. I am using Firefox on OSX. Which browser/OS are you using?

Comment: I'm using Google Chrome

Comment: Can't see it on IE11 on Win7 and Win10, or Chrome/Mac.

Comment: @JamesDouglas & others, the wiggle isn't noticeable with the current example, because the parent flex container simply grows - you'll notice the scrollbar length grow a little bit instead on a small enough viewport. Give the parent a fixed height instead of 50%, then it should show as advertised.

Comment: Can't see a noticeable wiggle on Chrome 67/Win 10